# match a token or rule N times

Tags: python, nltk, context-free-grammar

In Context free grammars how do you match a token or rule N times.

f.e. how do you do something like this :

```
S -> A{,3} B*
S2-> ((A B){1,2} C){,5}
A -> 'a'
B -> 'b'
```

OR if there is any other type of Grammar in nltk or elsewhere that can be used as sequence GENERATOR

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just repeat A three times? I can't really think of a good use case where you'd need this for large `N`?

Comment: i'm using it to generate sequences with increasing complexity

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to enumerate possibilities. It gets tedious, so automatic generation is a good option.

Eg.:

```
S → A3 Bstar
Bstar → ε
Bstar → Bstar B
A3 → ε
A3 → A
A3 → A A
A3 → A A A
```